# Neo4j return nodes indirectly connected to each other with merged relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset where the following query
returns the whole topology.

```
MATCH (na:node)-[ra:composition]-(ia:interface)-[rb:compound]-(ib:interface)-[rc:composition]-(nb:node)
RETURN na,ia,ib,nb
LIMIT 1000
```

I would like to merge ia and ib into only one relationship
so that I will only get nodes connected to each other and not their
intermediary interfaces.

Like this:

```
(na:node)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]-(nb:node)
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I correctly understand what you want to do, but shooting from the hip:

```
MATCH (na:node)-[ra:composition]-(ia:interface)-[rb:compound]-(ib:interface)-[rc:composition]-(nb:node)
WITH na,nb
LIMIT 1000
MERGE (na)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(nb)
RETURN count(*)
```

Run this query until count equals 0

Comment: Thanks, I dont want to modify the data. I only want to display the data with less information. That is, I want to see how nodes are connected to each other but I do not care about seeing the intermediary interfaces that in turn connects the nodes.

Comment: Why don't you just return na,nb then?

Comment: Then I don't get any relationships and the nodes look like they are not connected to each other even though they are indirectly connected to each other through ia and ib

Comment: Okay, I get your point now, the default visualization in the Neo4j browser can only show what is there. You cannot visualize it on a different way. If you really want to do these kind of things, you can create you own visualization with D3js, Sigma.js or Vivagraph.js to mention a few..